# Why does another module version gets updated as well when i run mvn version:set on a specific module (it shouldn't)

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I think i just found a "mvn version:set"-bug. I have a multi-module maven project. All the modules have the same parent. I want to set the versions of the modules independently of each other. So if module A is changed and module B is not, only module A can get a new version.
But when i try to make a SNAPSHOT version of 1 module. It also changes the version of another module, although i use the "-f /module_A/pom.xml" parameter to target module_A specifically.

Reproduction path:
I try to make a SNAPSHOT versions of all the modules individually (in the POM.xml's). so the version of each module get it's version incremented by 0.1 and gets "-SNAPSHOT" added behind it.

i have found that the following command does exactly that, but  1 module  behaves strange and it also gets updated when another module's version is updated.

mvn -f ./module_X/pom.xml versions:set -DnextSnapshot=true -DprocessParent=false -DprocessDependencies=false -Pjar

-I run the command in the root folder. In this folder all module folders are located.
-module_X should be replaced by the module folder name (module_A, module_B, module_C etc)
-"-DnextSnapshot=true" increments the version by 0.1 and adds "-SNAPSHOT"
-"-DprocessParent=false makes sure the parent's version in the module's POM is not changed.
-"DprocessDependencies=false" makes sure versions op dependencies are not changed.
"-f /module_A/pom.xml" parameter to target module_A specifically.

Ok so now it gets strange:
One of the modules get it's version updated when I run the command to update another module.

```
My set-up:

Parent-pom version = 1.3

module_A version = 0.5
module_A parent-version = 1.3

module_B version = 1.2
module_B parent-version = 1.1

module_C version = 1.2
module_C parent-version = 1.2

module_D version = 1.3
module_D parent-version = 1.2
```

**Module_C is the strange behaving module, it get's it's version updated to 1.3 if i try to update any of the other modules.**

**It seems like the module's version gets updated because it the parent-version and the version are identical and they're not the same as the version in the parent-POM

Module_B also doesn't have it's parent-version the same as the parent-pom, but this module doesn't get updated. (because 1.2 (its version) is not the same as 1.1 (it's parent version).

To test this theory i created i new module "module_E" with a version set to 1.1 and the parent version also set to 1.1. After updating the versions of any of the other modules the version of the module_E als gets set to 1.3! So the version will be updated to the latest parent version!

Does anybody know how i can prevent this behavior? It doesn't seem like desired behavior to me, right?

**Parent-POM bare minimum:**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<groupId>com.project.service</groupId>
<artifactId>project-parent-pom</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>module_A</module>
    <module>module_B</module>
    <module>module_C</module>
    <module>module_D</module>
</modules>
```

**module_C bare minumum:**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<name>module_A</name>
<packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>

<parent>
    <artifactId>project-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.project.service</groupId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>module_A</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
```

**the POM's for the module are all identical, except for the name (module_A, module_B etc, version and the parent-version)

The strange modules that behave strange are the ones that have the parent-version the same as the version (as shown in the "module bare minimum", where both are set to 1.2). in these cases the version is set to the same version as the version of the parent-POM. I tested also with a module with parent-version and version set to 1.5. And the same happened: the version got "updated" from 1.5 to 1.3.

Comment: Having a multi module build means by default having the same version number for all childs/parents. That's the real issue here.  Furthermore the question is: Which version of versions-maven-plugin do you use?

Comment: Please add the content of the POMs to the question. Trim them to the bare minimum which still shows the problem.

Comment: @khmarbaise, i would love to keep the version of the modules independent of each other, so i can also use them separately in other projects. 
The maven versions plugin version is 2.8.1

Comment: @illyaKysil, I added the bare minimum for the parent-POM and for module_C. All other modules are the same as module_C besides the name, version and parent-version

Comment: Using them separately has nothing to do with your structure nor with the version. If you have a multi module build and the same version you can use the artifacts also without any issue... ?

Comment: But wouldn't it be a bit strange, that the module would then sometimes get updated to a new version without there actually being any changed to the module?

Comment: Do you observe the same behavior (unexpected version change in a different module) when you add -DupdateMatchingVersions=false to the Maven invocation? See https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html#updateMatchingVersions for description.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a multi-module maven project. All the modules have the same parent. I want to set the versions of the modules independently of each other.

Given the module definitions in the question, you also want to set the version of the **parent** for each *child* independently. This contradicts **All the modules have the same parent**.

In order to achieve independent versions of the **parents** in the *child* modules, the latter should **not** reference parent POM in the `..` folder.

The definition of the module should look like following:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<name>module_A</name>
<packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>

<parent>
    <artifactId>project-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.project.service</groupId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<artifactId>module_A</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
```

Please note the `<relativePath/>` in `<parent>` tag. Maven will **always** fetch the **parent** definition from the repository in this case when constructing the effective POM for the *child* module.

Of course, you would need to release and deploy the **parent** module before even trying to build any of the *child* modules.

You may check [Google's Auto project](https://github.com/google/auto) @ GitHub to see the similar structure used.